# Flex 3 ColorPicker changes movieclip in SWFLoader

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, flash

How would I use a ColorPicker in Flex 3 to change the color of a movieclip which was dynamically loaded from an array into a SWFLoader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen to the ColorPicker's `change` event. When it fires, set the MovieClip's `opaqueBackground` color to the ColorPicker's `selectedColor` property